# Position elements

Tags: html, css

I have this snippet and I want to postion the elements like I have them on the photo[image: example] 
The red logo on top of the gray element without using negative margins

```css
.logo {
 width: 100px;
 height : 100px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius : 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color:red;
}
.chat {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #4a4444;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <section class="container">

   
  <div class="logo">
  </div> 

   <section class="chat">

  </section>
 </section>
```

Comment: you can also use transform:translate3d(0,-50px,0) on chat div and remove its margin. It will also work good

Answer (score 1):

**without negative margins**

**using** `position: relative;` **in** `container`  **class**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

**And**  `position: absolute;top: 50px;` **in** `chat` **class**

```
.chat {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #4a4444;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50px;
    }
```

**snippet Example**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.chat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #4a4444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">


  <div class="logo">
  </div>

  <section class="chat">

  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: i updated my answer please check it ..without using negative margins

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.chat {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #4a4444;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">


  <div class="logo">
  </div>

  <section class="chat">

  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I dont want to use negative margins because on resize page it doesnt look good

Comment: hello @RafaelDeSá  i updated my answer please check it ..without using negative margins

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo {
   width: 100px;
   height : 100px;
   position: relative;
   border-radius : 100px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 20px;
   background-color:red;
   top: -50px;

}
.chat {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: #4a4444;
   margin-top: 50px;
}

<section class="container"> 

    <section class="chat">

      <div class="logo">
      </div>

    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo {
 width: 100px;
 height : 100px;
 position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    top: 100px;
 border-radius : 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color:red;
        z-index: 1;
}
.chat {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: #4a4444;
 margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <section class="container">

   
  <div class="logo">
  </div> 

   <section class="chat">

  </section>
 </section>
```